# An application that includes 1000 elements is very slow

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application on WPF, one of the windows of which contains about 1000 elements(mainly ToggleButton, Button and TextBlock), each of which has its own style and animation. It works very slowly, with a scrolling performance of 2-4 frames per second. I've tried using virtualization, but it doesn't help. I also tried to disable anti-aliasing, but there was no effect.

I can't distribute the contents of the window into several, as this is required by the customer.
I ask for help, as I do not know how to solve this problem, thank you in advance.

```
<ScrollViewer Padding="0,0,0,10" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="30,0,0,10" Grid.Row="2" Style="{DynamicResource ScrollViewerStyle1}">
                        <ItemsControl VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" ItemsSource="{Binding SportsSettingsLive}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <DockPanel/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel  Margin="0,0,150,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="#131313">
                                
                                    <Grid x:Name="SportSettingsButton" Grid.Row="3" Width="324" Height="230" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                        <Grid.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=SportSettingsToggleButton}" Value="False">
                                                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="CloseBeginStoryboard">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="0" Duration="00:00:.2" />
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="CloseBeginStoryboard" />
                                                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=SportSettingsToggleButton}" Value="True">
                                                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OpenBeginStoryboard">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="230" Duration="00:00:.2" />
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="OpenBeginStoryboard" />
                                                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Grid.Style>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        <ToggleButton x:Name="CloseSportSettingsToggleButton" Height="45">
                                            <ToggleButton.Template>
                                                <ControlTemplate>
                                                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="22" Cursor="Hand">
                                                        <Border.Style>
                                                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                                <Setter Property="Background">
                                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                                                            <GradientStop Color="#2d2d2e" Offset="0" />
                                                                            <GradientStop Color="#171719" Offset="1" />
                                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                                </Setter>
                                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                                                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="IsMouseOverBeginStoryboard">
                                                                                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color">
                                                                                    <ColorAnimation To="White" Duration="0:0:0:.2" />
                                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                                                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                                                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                                                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="IsMouseOverBeginStoryboard" />
                                                                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                                                    </Trigger>
                                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                                            </Style>
                                                        </Border.Style>
                                                        <Grid>
                                                            <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                                                <Grid Width="19" Height="20">
                                                                    <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path2" Fill="#FFFE9A20">
                                                                        <Path.Data>
                                                                            <PathGeometry Figures="M9.50039 12.3504C10.0641 12.3504 10.6151 12.1832 11.0838 11.8701C11.5524 11.5569 11.9177 11.1118 12.1334 10.591C12.3492 10.0703 12.4056 9.49723 12.2956 8.94438C12.1857 8.39154 11.9142 7.88372 11.5156 7.48514C11.1171 7.08656 10.6092 6.81512 10.0564 6.70515C9.50355 6.59519 8.93051 6.65163 8.40974 6.86734C7.88897 7.08304 7.44386 7.44834 7.1307 7.91702C6.81754 8.3857 6.65039 8.93671 6.65039 9.50039C6.65039 10.2563 6.95066 10.9812 7.48514 11.5156C8.01961 12.0501 8.74452 12.3504 9.50039 12.3504ZM9.50039 7.60039C9.87617 7.60039 10.2435 7.71182 10.556 7.9206C10.8684 8.12937 11.112 8.42611 11.2558 8.77329C11.3996 9.12047 11.4372 9.5025 11.3639 9.87106C11.2906 10.2396 11.1096 10.5782 10.8439 10.8439C10.5782 11.1096 10.2396 11.2906 9.87106 11.3639C9.5025 11.4372 9.12047 11.3996 8.77329 11.2558C8.42611 11.112 8.12937 10.8684 7.9206 10.556C7.71182 10.2435 7.60039 9.87618 7.60039 9.50039C7.60039 8.99648 7.80057 8.51321 8.15689 8.15689C8.51321 7.80057 8.99648 7.60039 9.50039 7.60039Z" FillRule="NonZero" />
                                                                        </Path.Data>
                                                                    </Path>
                                                                    <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path4" Fill="#FFFE9A20">
                                                                        <Path.Data>
                                                                            <PathGeometry Figures="M1.98968 10.3858L0.958977 10.9963C0.535047 11.2479 0.227987 11.6571 0.10496 12.1344C-0.0180673 12.6118 0.0529505 13.1184 0.30248 13.5435L1.72051 15.9988C1.97206 16.4228 2.38126 16.7298 2.85861 16.8528C3.33596 16.9759 3.8426 16.9049 4.26772 16.6553L5.29186 16.0645C5.39078 16.0118 5.50156 15.9853 5.61363 15.9875C5.7257 15.9897 5.83533 16.0206 5.93208 16.0772C6.02884 16.1338 6.10948 16.2142 6.16634 16.3108C6.2232 16.4074 6.25438 16.517 6.25691 16.6291V17.8042C6.25155 18.2948 6.43915 18.768 6.7793 19.1216C7.11945 19.4753 7.58491 19.6812 8.0754 19.6949H10.9115C11.4054 19.6932 11.8786 19.4962 12.2279 19.1469C12.5772 18.7976 12.7742 18.3244 12.7759 17.8305V16.6488C12.7789 16.5364 12.8106 16.4267 12.8681 16.3302C12.9255 16.2336 13.0068 16.1534 13.1042 16.0973C13.204 16.0397 13.3172 16.0093 13.4324 16.0093C13.5477 16.0093 13.6609 16.0397 13.7607 16.0973L14.7782 16.6816C15.2034 16.9311 15.71 17.0021 16.1873 16.8791C16.6647 16.7561 17.0739 16.449 17.3254 16.0251L18.7435 13.5698C18.993 13.1447 19.064 12.638 18.941 12.1607C18.818 11.6833 18.5109 11.2741 18.087 11.0226L17.0366 10.412C16.9499 10.3515 16.8791 10.271 16.8302 10.1773C16.7814 10.0836 16.7558 9.97941 16.7558 9.87371C16.7558 9.76801 16.7814 9.66387 16.8302 9.57014C16.8791 9.47642 16.9499 9.39588 17.0366 9.33538L18.087 8.72484C18.5109 8.47329 18.818 8.06409 18.941 7.58674C19.064 7.1094 18.993 6.60276 18.7435 6.17763L17.3123 3.69608C17.0608 3.27215 16.6516 2.96509 16.1742 2.84206C15.6969 2.71903 15.1902 2.79005 14.7651 3.03958L13.7475 3.62386C13.6469 3.67892 13.5337 3.70666 13.419 3.70433C13.3044 3.702 13.1923 3.66967 13.094 3.61057C12.9958 3.55147 12.9147 3.46766 12.8589 3.36748C12.8031 3.2673 12.7745 3.15425 12.7759 3.03958V1.86445C12.7742 1.3705 12.5772 0.897274 12.2279 0.547996C11.8786 0.198718 11.4054 0.00173014 10.9115 0H8.0754C7.58145 0.00173014 7.10823 0.198718 6.75895 0.547996C6.40967 0.897274 6.21268 1.3705 6.21095 1.86445V3.04614C6.20734 3.15765 6.17537 3.26639 6.11806 3.36211C6.06076 3.45783 5.98 3.53736 5.88342 3.59321C5.78684 3.64905 5.67763 3.67937 5.56608 3.68128C5.45454 3.6832 5.34434 3.65666 5.2459 3.60417L4.24146 3.01332C3.81634 2.76379 3.3097 2.69277 2.83235 2.8158C2.355 2.93883 1.9458 3.24589 1.69425 3.66982L0.256526 6.15137C0.00699575 6.5765 -0.064022 7.08314 0.0590053 7.56048C0.182033 8.03783 0.489092 8.44703 0.913022 8.69858L1.96342 9.30912C2.05009 9.36962 2.12088 9.45016 2.16976 9.54388C2.21864 9.63761 2.24416 9.74175 2.24416 9.84745C2.24416 9.95315 2.21864 10.0573 2.16976 10.151C2.12088 10.2447 2.05009 10.3253 1.96342 10.3858H1.98968ZM2.64617 8.16682L1.61547 7.56284C1.4894 7.48876 1.39743 7.36815 1.35937 7.22696C1.32131 7.08577 1.3402 6.93528 1.41196 6.80787L2.8103 4.35257C2.84699 4.28751 2.89636 4.23047 2.9555 4.18485C3.01464 4.13922 3.08234 4.10593 3.15458 4.08695C3.22682 4.06797 3.30214 4.06369 3.37607 4.07436C3.45 4.08503 3.52103 4.11043 3.58496 4.14906L4.6091 4.73991C4.90651 4.9027 5.2409 4.98596 5.57992 4.98162C5.91894 4.97729 6.2511 4.88551 6.54425 4.71516C6.8374 4.54482 7.08161 4.30169 7.25324 4.00929C7.42487 3.71689 7.51812 3.38514 7.52394 3.04614V1.86445C7.52565 1.71872 7.5843 1.57945 7.68735 1.4764C7.7904 1.37335 7.92968 1.3147 8.0754 1.31299H10.9115C11.0572 1.3147 11.1965 1.37335 11.2995 1.4764C11.4026 1.57945 11.4612 1.71872 11.4629 1.86445V3.03958C11.4652 3.38293 11.5571 3.71973 11.7297 4.01657C11.9022 4.31342 12.1494 4.55999 12.4466 4.73184C12.7439 4.90369 13.0809 4.99485 13.4243 4.99626C13.7676 4.99768 14.1054 4.9093 14.404 4.73991L15.4019 4.14906C15.5293 4.0773 15.6798 4.05841 15.821 4.09647C15.9622 4.13453 16.0828 4.22649 16.1569 4.35257L17.5749 6.80787C17.6467 6.93528 17.6656 7.08577 17.6275 7.22696C17.5894 7.36815 17.4975 7.48876 17.3714 7.56284L16.321 8.16682C16.0331 8.34274 15.7952 8.58968 15.6301 8.88398C15.465 9.17826 15.3783 9.51003 15.3783 9.84745C15.3783 10.1849 15.465 10.5166 15.6301 10.8109C15.7952 11.1052 16.0331 11.3522 16.321 11.5281L17.3714 12.1321C17.4975 12.2061 17.5894 12.3267 17.6275 12.4679C17.6656 12.6091 17.6467 12.7596 17.5749 12.887L16.1569 15.3423C16.0828 15.4684 15.9622 15.5604 15.821 15.5984C15.6798 15.6365 15.5293 15.6176 15.4019 15.5458L14.3843 14.955C14.0849 14.7821 13.7453 14.6911 13.3996 14.6911C13.0539 14.6911 12.7142 14.7821 12.4148 14.955C12.1206 15.1279 11.8774 15.3758 11.7102 15.6734C11.543 15.9709 11.4577 16.3075 11.4629 16.6488V17.8305C11.4612 17.9762 11.4026 18.1155 11.2995 18.2185C11.1965 18.3216 11.0572 18.3802 10.9115 18.3819H8.0754C7.92968 18.3802 7.7904 18.3216 7.68735 18.2185C7.5843 18.1155 7.52565 17.9762 7.52394 17.8305V16.6553C7.52394 16.133 7.31645 15.632 6.94709 15.2627C6.57774 14.8933 6.0768 14.6858 5.55445 14.6858C5.21293 14.6849 4.87742 14.7756 4.58284 14.9484L3.58496 15.5458C3.45755 15.6176 3.30706 15.6365 3.16587 15.5984C3.02468 15.5604 2.90407 15.4684 2.82999 15.3423L1.39227 12.887C1.32211 12.7572 1.30621 12.605 1.34804 12.4635C1.38987 12.322 1.48602 12.2028 1.61547 12.1321L2.66587 11.5281C2.9538 11.3522 3.19171 11.1052 3.35678 10.8109C3.52184 10.5166 3.60853 10.1849 3.60853 9.84745C3.60853 9.51003 3.52184 9.17826 3.35678 8.88398C3.19171 8.58968 2.9538 8.34274 2.66587 8.16682H2.64617Z" FillRule="NonZero" />
                                                                        </Path.Data>
                                                                    </Path>
                                                                </Grid>
                                                                <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="Скрыть" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle1}" Foreground="#FE9A20" />
                                                                <Path Margin="18,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" StrokeThickness="1.5" Stroke="#FFFE9A20" StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round">
                                                                    <Path.Data>
                                                                        <PathGeometry Figures="M1 6L6.5 1L12 6" FillRule="NonZero" />
                                                                    </Path.Data>
                                                                </Path>
                                                            </DockPanel>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </Border>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </ToggleButton.Template>
                                        </ToggleButton>
                                        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="45" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Доход:" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="16" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle1}" />
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Коэф:" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="16" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle1}" />
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Время:" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="16" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle1}" />

                                            <uc:NumericUpDown Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="93" Prefix="от" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Postfix="%" />
                                            <uc:NumericUpDown Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="93" Prefix="от" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                            <uc:NumericUpDown Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Width="93" Prefix="от" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Postfix="сек" />

                                            <uc:NumericUpDown Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Width="93" Prefix="до" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Postfix="%" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                            <uc:NumericUpDown Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Width="93" Prefix="до" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                            <uc:NumericUpDown Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Width="93" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Prefix="до" Postfix="сек" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>

                                <DockPanel>
                                    <ToggleButton Width="32" Height="32" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonRefresh}" />
                                    <ToggleButton Width="32" Height="32" Margin="6,0,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonClock}" />
                                            <ToggleButton Margin="16,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonStyle}"/>
                                    <Border Padding="30,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="20" Height="40">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#2d2d2e" Offset="0" />
                                                <GradientStop Color="#171719" Offset="1" />
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ESport,Converter={StaticResource ESportToStringConverter}}" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FE9A20" FontFamily="{DynamicResource MontserratAlternates}" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
                                    </Border>
                                    <Button Width="22" Height="18" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonOpenSettings}" Margin="12,0" Cursor="Hand" Background="Transparent" />
                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="SportSettingsToggleButton" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=CloseSportSettingsToggleButton}" Width="19" Height="19" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonStyle1}" Cursor="Hand" />
                                </DockPanel>
                                <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding BetFilters}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <DockPanel Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                                <ToggleButton Width="32" Height="32" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonRefresh}" />
                                                <ToggleButton Width="32" Height="32" Margin="6,0,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonClock}" />
                                                <ToggleButton Margin="16,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonStyle}"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding EPositiveBetType,Converter={StaticResource EPositiveBetTypeToNameConverter}}" Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle1}" />
                                            </DockPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>

                            </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: The elements in the window are loaded from the collection during its launch

Comment: "*I've tried using virtualization, but it doesn't help.*" - why not? It should actually be the solution. However, a DockPanel as ItemsPanel won't do.